# How can I check a string of words to see if they are an anagram of one word

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to figure out a javascript function that will help resolve this test.  I need to be able to determine if the string of words (var matches) that is given is an anagram of the word that I am running through (var subject).  In this case there would not be a match.  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

```
var anagram = require('./anagram');

describe('Anagram', function() {

    it("no matches",function() {
        var subject = anagram("diaper");
        var matches = subject.matches([ "hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"]);

        expect(matches).toEqual([]);
    });
});
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (subject.length != matches[i].length) {
        return false
    } else if (subject.length == matches[i].length){
    var anagram = function(subject, matches) {
        return subject.split("").sort("").join("") === matches[i].split("").sort("").join("");
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you using any external libraries? Such as underscore.js?

Comment: No, I am not currently using any but if I were to use underscore would I use the _.each?

Comment: I was thinking _.filter actually. Its not hard to do otherwise, I just think that the underscore way is pretty clean.

Comment: Oh, ok I will have to look into that.  Could you give me some tips on how to solve this problem without _.filter?

Comment: Certainly. Let me run a fiddle and see if I can get a clean response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hn8r4v3u/2/

I alphabetized the letters within the word, as you were doing, in a function.

```
function getAlphaSortedWord(word) {
    var baseWordCharArray = word.split("");
    baseWordCharArray.sort();
    return baseWordCharArray.join("");
}
```

The code has a set up:

```
var baseWord = getAlphaSortedWord("bob");
var thingsToCheck = ["obb", "2", "bob", "", "bo", "ob"];
```

And then solves it two ways, once with filter and once without it.

```
var matches = _.filter(thingsToCheck, function (str) {
    return (baseWord === getAlphaSortedWord(str));
});


var matches2 = [];
for (index = 0; index < thingsToCheck.length; index++) {
    if (baseWord === getAlphaSortedWord(thingsToCheck[index])) {
        matches2.push(thingsToCheck[index]);
    }
}
```

You should be able to use these to tie in with your real data for the test to pass.

NOTE, I would add some sanity for "is string" to my function if this is going to be production code.

Answer (score 0):

Found here and it works: https://gist.github.com/AlbertoElias/10005056

```
function areAnagrams(a, b) {
    var c = false;
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return c;
    }

    var hashMap = {};
    var char;
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        char = a[i];
        hashMap[char] = hashMap[char] !== undefined ? hashMap[char]+1 : 1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        char = b[i];
        if (hashMap[char] !== undefined) {
            if (hashMap[char] > 1) {
                hashMap[char]--;
            } else {
                delete hashMap[char];
            }
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }

    if (Object.keys(hashMap).length === 0) c = true;

    return c;
}
```